# Position div with relative position to the bottom inside absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have div with `position:relative` inside main div.

I would like to position `div` with `id=divBottom` to the bottom of the main div. Is this possible? If I set `bottom=0` nothing happens because it's relatively positioned and `bottom=0` is counted from div's relative position.

Is it possible to do this, without changing `position` of `divBottom` to absolute? I know I can do this, but I would like `divBottom` to remain relatively positioned.

Here is the code:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;border:5px solid black;">
  <div id="divBottom" style="width:30%;height:30%;border:1px solid black;position:relative;bottom:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify position:relative, then you can use top or bottom, and left or right to move the element relative to where it would normally occur in the document.

Learning css 10 position steps [click here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

another one [click here too](http://learnlayout.com/position.html)

Normally we use like this way

```html
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;border:5px solid black;">
  <div id="divBottom" style="width:30%;height:30%;border:1px solid black;position:absolute;bottom:0;"></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to keep the position relative, you can add

```
top: 70%
```

to divBottom's style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `bottom:0` to `top: 70%` on `divBottom` as it's 30% height fixed height.

```html
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;border:5px solid black;">
  
  
  <div id="divBottom" style="width:30%;height:30%;border:1px solid black;position:relative; top:70%;"></div>
  
  
  
</div>
```